# Angular calling two functions on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to perform two operations on ng-click. Currently it is performing one. On my javascript side, I have a variable *totalMoviesWatched* I'd like to increment on ng-click as well.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="movie in MovieDB.movies" ng-show="movie.Response == 'True'" ng-class="{ 'strikeout': movie.watched }" >
 <td><a ng-click="movie.watched = true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true" ng-hide="movie.watched"></span></a></td>
```

So, something like:

```
<a ng-click="movie.watched = true, totalMoviesWatched += 1">
```

??

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a semi-colon to separate statements:

```
<a ng-click="movie.watched = true; totalMoviesWatched = totalMoviesWatched + 1"> <!--Angular can't figure out += inline-->
```

Or just do both of these operations inside one function:

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {
    $scope.movie.watched = true;
    $scope.totalMoviesWatched++;
}

<a ng-click="myFunc()">
```

Comment: I also thought about this, but looks like Angular can't parse `+= 1` part for some reason.

Comment: @dfsq -- Gah - hate that...it also can't do `indexOf` if you ever come across that :D - editing...

Comment: Anyway, your second version `ng-click="myFunc()"` is even better, keep template cleaner as to me.

Comment: so, this is actually not working. only the function that is declared first executes.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it using this expression:

```
ng-click="movie.watched = true; totalMoviesWatched = totalMoviesWatched + 1"
```